# Can event viewer in Windows 2000 consume ETW trace?

Tags: windows-2000

I think in Windows 2000 the events logged are in binary format as compared to the XML format in Windows Vista. I want to know whether its possible for the event viewer in Windows 2000 to consume the events from ETW Trace in real-time. I seriously doubt whether that functionality is made available in Vista when the event tracing and logging was rewritten for Event viewer. Please confirm! Is there any way to make the event viewer in Windows 2000 consume the ETW Traces real-time? If yes, Please tell me how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't! Better use normal event logging rather than ETW in Windows 2000.